# Strange behavior with dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is my small plugin: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1a5svhx/16/)

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.my_alert = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).bind("click", function(e) {
                alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
            });
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myalert').my_alert();

    $('.add-more').click(function() {
        var uniq = new Date().valueOf();
        var newHtml = "<button class='myalert' data-id='" + uniq + "' >show alert</button>";
        $('body').append(newHtml);
        $('.myalert').my_alert();
    });
});
```

If I call the plugin after adding a new button then `alert` the `id` on the old item more than once, but if I did not call it after adding a new button, then it will not work on the new button.

Where am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix for your issue [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1a5svhx/18/)

```
$(function(){
$.fn.my_alert = function(){
   this.each(function() {  
            $( this ).bind("click",function(e){ 
               alert($( this ).attr('data-id'));
             });
        });
    } 
 });


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.myalert').my_alert();
   $('.add-more').click(function() {
     var uniq =  new Date().valueOf();
      var newHtml = $("<button class='myalert' data-id='"+uniq+"' >show alert</button>");
    $('body').append(newHtml);
    newHtml.my_alert();
    });
});
```

Comment: Same problem with your answer too as Rory Answer, if i add other html along with button then it will not work check here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brilliantcoder/u1a5svhx/23/)

Comment: $('<div ><button class="myalert" data-id="' + uniq + '">show alert</button>sdfdsfsdf dfds gfvd g</div>').appendTo('body').find('[data-id=' + uniq + ']').my_alert();

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because when you create a new `button` you're instantiating another instance of your plugin on *all* the `.myalert` elements. Instead, just instantiate it on the new button, like this:

```
$('.add-more').click(function() {
    var uniq = new Date().valueOf();
    $('<button class="myalert" data-id="' + uniq + '">show alert</button>').appendTo('body').my_alert();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/u1a5svhx/21/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this will work only if i add button, but if i add other html with button? Then this is not working. like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brilliantcoder/u1a5svhx/23/)  Then what to do

Comment: That's because when you add another wrapping element around the button, you're calling `my_alert` on that `div`, instead of the button. To do what you require there, add the new div, then prepend the button to it, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/u1a5svhx/26/. Also note the added `return` in the plugin code to enable method chaining. If you have any further issues with this, I would suggest you start a new question including all the details about the behaviour you want to achieve.